# What is the "Shell Namespace" way to create a new folder?

Tags: c++, windows, com, windows-shell

Obviously this is trivial to do with win32 api - CreateDirectory().  But I'm trying to host an IShellView, and would like to do this the most shell-oriented way.  I would have thought that there would be a createobject or createfolder or some such from an IShellFolder.  But neither IShellView nor IShellFolder nor even IFolderView seem to have anything quite like this.

Is there a Shell-programming way to create a new folder?  Or do I need to create a folder using a pathname, the old-fashioned way?

If I have to do it via CreateDirectory(), then my next question might be: any ideas as to how to get the IShellView / IFolderView to actually see this new object and display it to the user?

Motivation: Creating my own File Dialog replacement and I want to provide the "new folder" toolbar icon functionality of the standard XP-style file dialog.

EDIT: I went ahead and created something that basically works, using CreateDirectory.  However, I'm still hoping that there's a better way to do this, but so that you can see how that works, and to offer better ideas as to solve this issue better:

```
    PidlUtils::Pidl pidl(m_folder);
    CFilename folderName(GetDisplayNameOf(pidl), "New Folder");
    for (int i = 2; folderName.Exists(); ++i)
        folderName.SetFullName(FString("New Folder (%d)", i));
    if (!CPathname::Create(folderName, false))
        throw CContextException("Unable to create a new folder here: ");

    // get the PIDL for the newly created folder
    PidlUtils::Pidl pidlNew;
#ifdef UNICODE
    const wchar_t * wszName = folderName.c_str();
#else
    wchar_t wszName[MAX_PATH];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, folderName.GetFullName(), -1, wszName, MAX_PATH);
#endif
    m_hresult = m_folder->ParseDisplayName(NULL, NULL, wszName, NULL, pidlNew, NULL);
    if (FAILED(m_hresult))
        throw CLabeledException(FString("Unable to get the PIDL for the new folder: 0x%X", m_hresult));

    // upgrade our interface so we can select & rename it
    CComQIPtr<IShellView2> sv2(m_shell_view);
    if (!sv2)
        throw CLabeledException("Unable to obtain the IShellView2 we need to rename the newly created folder.");

    // force it to see thew new folder
    sv2->Refresh();

    // select the new folder, and begin the rename process
    m_hresult = sv2->SelectAndPositionItem(pidlNew, SVSI_EDIT|SVSI_DESELECTOTHERS|SVSI_ENSUREVISIBLE|SVSI_POSITIONITEM, NULL);
    if (FAILED(m_hresult))
        throw CLabeledException(FString("Unable to select and position the new folder item: 0x%X", m_hresult));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell folders usually implement the IStorage interface, so this is pretty simple. For example, the following creates a folder named "abcd" on the desktop:

```
  CComPtr<IShellFolder> pDesktop;
  HRESULT hr = SHGetDesktopFolder(&pDesktop);
  if (FAILED(hr)) return;
  CComQIPtr<IStorage> pStorage(pDesktop);
  if (!pStorage) return;
  CComPtr<IStorage> dummy;
  hr = pStorage->CreateStorage(L"abcd", STGM_FAILIFTHERE, 0, 0, &dummy);
```

Comment: Thank you!  Having to mix COM and Win32 to accomplish this seemed bizarre.  Of course, this COM Shell way may well bottom out in a call to "CreateDirectory()"!  lol ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can [get IContextMenu](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327569) and look for sub menus, but why bother, just call [SHChangeNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762118(VS.85).aspx) after you call CreateDirectory

Comment: Getting an IContextMenu sounds like it might be very useful for obtaining the list of view options in a given shell view (details, small icons, etc.).  Are you saying I could try to dig up the command for create new folder from within a context menu and invoke that?  Yeah, if that's what you mean, that sounds like a bad idea!  I was hopeing for more like IFolderView::CreateObject() or some such.

Comment: Yes.. Call SHChangeNotify as this is the correct way to do it.  Poking around in the IContextMenu is a good way to ensure your program breaks on the next version of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The Win32 API function CreateDirectory seems to be the "correct way".  At least, I can find nothing better - and the answers here don't really shed any light on a better way to do it.

Comment: That only works if you're adding a folder to the filesystem.