# IExplorerbrowser IFolderview2 create folder post notification

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, windows-shell

I have a MFC application that uses IExplorerBrowser interface to implement the windows shell inside my application. In this application, I have a button that user can click and create a folder inside the shell view of the explorer. After the folder gets created, the application should allow the user to rename the folder. In other words, I want it to work exactly the same way as user creates folder in the Windows explorer. I used NewItem method of IFileOperations interface to create the folder. Here is my exact code of creating a folder inside my application

```
HRESULT CreateFolder( __in IShellItem *pDestinationFolder, PCWSTR pszNewName )
{
HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx( NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE );
if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
{
    CComPtr<IFileOperation> pFileOperation;
    hr = CoCreateInstance( CLSID_FileOperation,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_ALL,
        IID_PPV_ARGS( &pFileOperation ) );
    if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
    {
        hr = pFileOperation->SetOperationFlags( FOF_NO_UI );
        if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
        {
            hr = pFileOperation->NewItem( pDestinationFolder, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY, pszNewName, NULL, NULL );
            if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
            {
                hr = pFileOperation->PerformOperations();
            }
        }


    }
}
CoUninitialize();
return hr;
}
```

After I call CreateFolder(...), I put the folder to select mode by using the SelectItem method of IFolderView2 interface. Here is the code to put the folder in Edit mode:

```
HRESULT hr = m_pIExplorerBrowser->GetCurrentView( IID_PPV_ARGS( pFolderView2 ) );
if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
pFolderView2->SelectItem( nLastCreatedFolderIndex, SVSI_EDIT );
```

The problem is that CreateFolder finishes later than my SelectItem method call. I have been looking for an event that will tell me when the view gets updated by CreateFolder so that i can send my SelectItem method after that.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to duplicate anything in `IExplorerBrowser` to make it look like explorer browser, when it is already an exact duplicate. Maybe you want to change explorer's behavior, in that case it might be easier to work with `CMFCShellListCtrl`

Comment: I am not trying to duplicate IExplorerbrowser. IExplorerbrowser meets all my requirements. But the issue is that in my application, user can create a folder by clicking a button that is not part of the shell. When they do that, I still want users to be able to type the name of the folder. I am basically looking for a event that is raised when new folder appear on the shellview.

Comment: I see what you mean. But reading your question again, I don't think you need event handling. `pFileOperation->PerformOperations()` does not return until directory is created. It's not like `PostMessage`. You should check that again.

Comment: PerformOperations create a new item synchronously, but the shellview doesn't get updated right away. There is a delay between the peformoperations and when the shellview gets updated. I also tried the IFileOperationProgressSink and call the selectitem method on PostNewItem event but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my question. It was already asked as another question on stackoverflow. 
[What is the "Shell Namespace" way to create a new folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773381/what-is-the-shell-namespace-way-to-create-a-new-folder)